# cakePHP : combining 2 actions and loading all players and also one player that changes

Tags: php, cakephp, view, controller, action

In my index (/players) view I have a carousel with images of a bunch of players. When I click on an Image I go to the view screen of the clicked player (/players/view/1).

Now I want to only have an index screen with that carousel of player images and after I click on an Image I want the information of that player on that same index screen.

How would I best combine the index and view so that I can click on a player image and retrieve his information on the same page? The goal is to have one view file and one action in the controller. So how can I put find('all') and find('first') in one action?

Now I have /players and /players/view/1.
I want to have for instance /players/1 so it loads on the same page. However this will still give a page load I think.

Eventually I don't want a page load, but only a content change.

index action of PlayersController (gives me all the players) :

```
public function index() {
    $this->layout = 'default_front_players';
    $this->Player->recursive = 0;
    //$this->Player->find('all');
    $this->set('players', $this->Paginator->paginate());
}
```

view action of PlayersController (gives me the player that has been clicked) :

```
public function view($id = null) {
    $this->layout = 'default_front_players';

    if (!$this->Player->exists($id)) {
        throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid player'));
    }
    $options = array('conditions' => array('Player.' . $this->Player->primaryKey => $id));

    $this->set('player', $this->Player->find('first', $options));

}
```

**UPDATE**

**First case**

This gives me all the players and gives me also one player (atm player 143, the last one in the database), problem is that when I click on a players image the player stays on player 143. The url changes to players/index/{number of clicked player}

```
public function index($id = null) {
    $this->layout = 'default_front_players';
    $this->Player->recursive = 0;

    $players = $this->Player->find('all');
    $this->set(compact('players'));

    $options = array('conditions' => array('Player.' . $this->Player->primaryKey => $id));
    $player = $this->set('player', $this->Player->find('first', $options));
}
```

**Second case**

This doesn't shows me the player images, but when I change the url, it gives me the content of the player which id I give in the URL.

```
public function index($id = null) {
    $this->layout = 'default_front_players';
    $this->Player->recursive = 0;

    //$players = $this->Player->find('all');
    //$this->Paginator->settings = $this->paginator_players;
    $this->set('players');

    $options = array('conditions' => array('Player.' . $this->Player->primaryKey => $id));

    $player = $this->set('player', $this->Player->find('first', $options));
}
```

If I go to /players or players/index I don't get any values.

How can I combine these 2?

Comment: "Best approach" might bring opinion-based answers. Could you be more specific? Best approach regarding best practices? Performance? Less code writing?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried ajax and routes to achieve a content refresh ( essentially creating your own api call to internal resources )?  I use cakephp for my own side project, and needed a way to circumvent the whole controller, view load mechanism for a faster UI experience.

The gist is including jquery in your template or layout file.  When a certain route or url is called ( this requires a route to be setup in your routes.php file in app/config relatively from your apps root folder ) , fire the ajax call to fetch the content and dynamically update the dom without having to reload the page.

This suggestion might open up a whole new can of worms for you, but its achievable I think.

Comment: Thanks, but first I need to find a way to combine the index and view.